# Transferring my OpenGL PC game to PS4 and/or XBox One

Tags: opengl, xbox, playstation4

I want to transfer my OpenGL PC game to consoles, PS4 and/or XBox One.

It's a complex application, where many calculations (incl. fast fourier transformations) via FBOs and Transformfeedback are performed within OpenGL. What is the best way to bring it to the PS4?

Or is it easier to implement the game in an engine like Unity or Unreal. As far as I know they have console support? An advantage would be that we could offer our methods as plugin/asset. We are planning to do this too.

There are a lot of glsl-shaders and OpenGL-Api-Calls. Is it possible at all to "translate" that into an engine like unreal? Or would we have to use the engines "predefined" rendnering mechanisms? We basically need shaders operating on floating point textures, changing render targets frequently and transform feedback if possible. We also need low level acces to shading attributes like changing pointsize in the vertex shader etc.

And I really would like to know which is less work. I could image that it is possible to absctract all the Api-Calls in classes/functions and then where first all the OpenGL-calls are implemted and then we would do an implemetation for the console api. Is this realistic on the PS4 Api?

I know that Direct X will have a different design and therefore abstraction itself won't be enough. I believe porting to an engine might be even more work as you have to respect its structures.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question we can answer within the scope of this site. Porting a game to a new platform is a huge process that will differ substantially based on the details of your project, and for consoles much of the information can't be discussed outside the official dev forums for NDA reasons. As for switching to another engine, we don't do technology recommendations here, so all we can really say is that would be a porting job of its own, whichever engine you go with (though hopefully, once you've done that work once, the engine would handle much of the cross-platform details)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, I asked [a similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106495/which-consoles-may-i-target-with-opengl) last year, and the answer was clear: neither PS4 nor Xbox One have OpenGL support. If you want to make your game works on them without using another engine, you will have to rewrite the entire rendering API (anything directly related to OpenGL or shaders) into an API supported by a console.

Unity and Unreal engines do have PS4 and Xbox One supports. But as rendering API calls are often the deepest and least accessible part in game engines, it will be hard to "translate" it from your own code to one of them, especially if your rendering mechanism is different from theirs (which is most probable).
And of course, it would mean totally rewrite your game if you didn't use the same language than the one used by those engines (C++ for Unreal and C#/JavaScript for Unity).

So any solution would require a lot of work. But if you are making complex calculations using every mechanism of the rendering API, the first one shall give you more possibilities.